# Facebook chat rooms using XMPP

Tags: ios, facebook, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

I'm trying to create mobile based chat app.

Basically, I want users to connect to Facebook with their Facebook account (Using the [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework))

I would like to have pre-existing rooms where users can join. I've noticed that XMPPFramework does support [XEP-0045](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/tree/master/Extensions/XEP-0045) extension, but I'm not sure how to create rooms on Facebook chat (it is possible at all?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible because the Facebook XMPP server supports no MUC itself and they also don't federate with the XMPP network.

Comment: Yes, Facebook Chat API is sucks :(
No room support, even in roadmap