# Send XMPP message element multiple destinations (Facebook Chat API)

Tags: ios, facebook, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

I'm using Facebook Chat API in an iOS app. I already can send a message successfully to a Facebook friend. Now I'm wondering if a can send the same message to multiple recipients.

I don't know if it's technically possible or there's any limitation about that.

I know that I can create N messages for N users and send one by one. But depending on the number of Facebook friends that the user can select, it can take a long time until all the messages are delivered. If this is the only case, should I open one different thread for each message that is going to be sent with the XMPP stream?

I appreciate any resolution or clue for this question.

Answer (score 2):

There's an XMPP extension [XEP-0033: Extended Stanza Addressing](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0033.html) which supports multicasting messages to multiple recipients. The extension has progressed to draft status, however few XMPP servers or clients support it. I doubt Facebook Chat does, and couldn't find any mention in the XMPPFramework source.

I don't think there's a better way than sending the same message to multiple recipients. Some servers may require you to pause between sending lots of identical messages, and I wouldn't be surprised if that were true of Facebook Chat.

Multi-User Chat is another way to accomplish this with XMPP, but unfortunately [Facebook Chat doesn't support MUC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175899/facebook-chat-rooms-using-xmpp).